# I have confusion in Git workflow need recommendation

Tags: git

[image: git flow of working]

**Question is so simple but help me to clear my concepts :)**

I am working on a project and make a branch for any new feature, so sometimes in a day, I create more than 4 branches.

For every branch first I check master then create a new branch.

#### Question:

When we merge all branches one by one its results become all code is merged like I show in the picture or something different than that.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking.  If the changes are non-conflicting, then yes, the end result will be the union of all the changes.  If they conflict, then you'll need to explicitly deal with merge conflicts.

Comment: I am just asking what is the best way to use git when you have 3 person team and all work on the same module.

Answer (score 0):

There will be conflicts, assuming first you merge br1, then br2 and br3:

when you merge branch1 with master, line 1-> same, line 2 added by 'DEF' and no merge conflicts.

when you merge branch2 with master, there is conflict in line 2 as line 2 of master contains DEF, so you have to resolve it.

similarly for branch3, will depend on how you resolved above conflict.

Comment: so, whats the best practice to handle these conflicts?

Comment: try to keep your local repo in sync with upstream.

Comment: @Abishek Kumar
- Its routine always merges every branch on day end. and in the morning first, pull updated data and start working but now I am confusing if I made four branches in a day they surely conflicted :/
- Do you think its good practices to create only one branch a day ?